# Real estate: estimating average residence time based on limited time date

Tags: estimation

I've been collecting real estate transactions in my neighborhood for a while and have data about resales since 2017. The neighborhood was established in 2005, so much longer than what I have data for.

I'm looking to estimate average residence time (time between sales of a single home) in two ways:

1. (# of total homes) / (# sales in the last 12 months)
   This is more or less a proxy estimate since it doesn't include an actual sale of a single home twice, as if it were a longitudinal sample. The average residence time that I get out of this is very comparable to the expected (10-12 years).
2. actual longitudinal tracking of sales
   This method (for now) is severely flawed because the length of the dataset is much shorter than the age of the neighborhood. I cannot seriously state that homes are being sold every 22 months because a small fraction of homes that I have longitudinal data for.

The figure shows the CDF for (time of sale)-(time of next listing) for the homes I have data for.
[image]

Besides collecting data for the next 20 years or so, is there a way to get an estimate out of the data I already have?

Comment: Overview of the data set can be found in https://github.com/robhanssen/glenlake-homesale-v2/blob/main/sources/homesalesdata-source.csv

Comment: One of your main issues would seem to be properly dealing with [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29) (particularly on the right in this case). To estimate a mean in the presence of censoring you'll need some explicit parametric model (and you'll be somewhat reliant on the assumptions in the shape of the upper tail beyond your observation period).